# Remove Non-repeating Values from an Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat

I have a large array in which certain row values repeat (8 repeats max). How can I only pull the repeated row values and their subsequent columns?

I should mention that the first column is an ID column (where I want to look for repeats), but the repeated ID values have different column values.

```
ID = [1;2;4;10;7;1;5;4]
```

I want to locate row n of both instances of 1, and 4

Output should be:

```
ID = [1;4;1;4]
```

or the sorted version:

```
ID=[1;1;4;4]
```

Either version is workable.

I believe I need a loop and the use of the find function

Comment: I want to remove all non-repeating values and keep all instances of all repeating values. Sorting is ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), in combination with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), [`find`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) this way:

```
[n, bin] = histc(A, unique(A));
multiple = find(n > 1);
index = find(ismember(bin, multiple))
index =
     1
     3
     6
     8
```

Which gives:

```
ID(index)
     1
     4
     1
     4
```

Answer (score 2):

The sorted approach is also simple:

```
ID = sort(ID);
index = find(ID(2:end) == ID(1:end-1));
ID = ID(index);
```